# Flash player on Windows 10

Tags: java, flash

I am currently trying to get an old Windows 7 application using Java and Flash (more specifically R6 45) to work on windows 10. It appears that Windows 10 does not allow to install these older versions of flash. Does anyone know a work around? I am hoping to get flash installed verses rewriting this entire application (it does video processing).

Comment: For security reasons, you **should not do that**.

Comment: Do not install an old version of these tools - they pose security risks. If you need to run them, create an isolated Windows 7 virtual machine and run them there.

Comment: I am not concerned about security holes as these PCs will not be online.